# SqlAlchemy OperationalError using Case

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, case

This is a bit of code I'm writing for a plugin for a bit of software (Anki).

```
for i in date:
    self.deck.s.execute(
    """CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM :table WHERE day=date( :i )) THEN
         UPDATE :table SET WHERE day=date(:i)
       ELSE
         INSERT INTO :table (day, matureRise) VALUES ( date( :i ),1)
       END""", {'table':STATSTABLE,'i':i})
```

The problem is that it keeps throwing an OperationalError. Specifically I'm getting:

```
sqlalchemy.engine.default", line 299, in do_execute
OperationalError: (OperationalError) near "CASE": syntax error u'CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ? WHERE day=date( ? )) THEN\nUPDATE ? SET WHERE day=date(?)\nELSE\nINSERT INTO ? (day, matureRise) VALUES ( date( ? ),1) END' ('stats_2', (u'2011-05-03',), 'stats_2', (u'2011-05-03',), 'stats_2', (u'2011-05-03',))
```

I've tried a number of things but I haven't been able to figure out whats wrong. I'm not very familiar with sqlalchemy so I'm wondering if maybe there's some nuance in supplying raw SQL that I'm missing.

Comment: Uhh.. ever heard of `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Comment: Didn't fix anything. Still getting an error:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) near "ON": syntax error u"INSERT INTO stats_2 (day, matureRise) VALUES ( date( '2011-05-03' ),1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE matureRise=matureRise+1

Comment: It would help, if you would tell what database you are using. That solution I offered is MySQL-specific and isn't supported on SQLite.

Comment: Yes, the database is SQLite. I guess I incorrectly assumed that SQLAlchemy was mostly an interface library for SQLite databases. I figured out a solution after a bit of work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql://test:test@localhost/test', echo=True)
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Date, Column, Integer


Base = declarative_base()



class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    day = Column(Date, unique=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    c = engine.connect()
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO users(day) VALUES ('2012-03-05') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE day='2012-03-04'""")
```

When i run this file first time i get log like

```
2012-03-05 12:39:42,202 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2012-03-05 12:39:42,202 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2012-03-05 12:39:42,204 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%%'
2012-03-05 12:39:42,204 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2012-03-05 12:39:42,205 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'
2012-03-05 12:39:42,205 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2012-03-05 12:39:42,206 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW COLLATION
2012-03-05 12:39:42,206 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2012-03-05 12:39:42,209 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2012-03-05 12:39:42,209 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2012-03-05 12:39:42,210 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine DESCRIBE `users`
2012-03-05 12:39:42,210 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2012-03-05 12:39:42,211 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO users(day) VALUES ('2012-03-05') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE day='2012-03-04'
2012-03-05 12:39:42,211 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2012-03-05 12:39:42,212 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

Then i check in database

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+------------+
| id | day        |
+----+------------+
|  8 | 2012-03-05 |
+----+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then I run the program again

and check the mysql again.

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+------------+
| id | day        |
+----+------------+
|  8 | 2012-03-04 |
+----+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I eventually figured out a workaround/hack for my problem. I ended up using a INSERT OR IGNORE clause and then checking for no return and then UPDATING. You're method would actually probably work  if I set my day field as the KEY. I like it for its simplicity and that's what I had been searching for originally since I knew it should be possible to INSERT or UPDATE in the same SQL execution. I'll give the answer to you. Thanks.